# How to kill Windows service process stuck at starting?

Tags: windows-service

Steps like

1. Copy service name from service properties
2. In administrator's command line run: 
   `sc queryex {here paste service name}`, mark PID
3. Run `taskkill /f /pid {here paste PID}`

do not work, because process is not started yet (stuck at starting), so has no PID.

Any solution except server restart?

Comment: To prevent misunderstandings: I'm not concerned with getting an accepted answer. I give only an explanation how Serverfault works. Serverfault is a Q & A platform and the accepted answer should fit the question. This ensures that someone with a similar problem receives a correct answer. Your accepted answer fits your problem but not the question you asked.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change the startup type of that service to `Manual` - that can resolve your issue

Comment: Although, this particular thing did not help, it gave me a clue on changing startup type, and setting it to Disabled helped.

Comment: In my scenario, the service was stuck in starting because it was configured in the recovery tab to restart indefinitely.  I typed in the wrong password, and that locked the account in AD.  Switching startup type to manual stopped the indefinite restart loop allowed me to unlock the account in AD and correct the credentials.

Answer (score 7):

- Retrieve the command line of your service from the service properties (services.msc)
- Start [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
- In Process Explorer make the command line visible (View / Select Columns / Command line)
- locate the process and kill it (Del)

Example command line: `C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs`

Comment: Thank you for sharing this tool and info on how to use it! For my particular case, unforunately, service kept coming back again and again

Comment: @avj In that case, try rebooting your box and then kill the exe.